# angular 6 woocommerce REST authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, woocommerce, angular6

I am trying to connect my woocommerce rest api with angular 6.

```
export class RestService {
  _urlwc = 'http://127.0.0.1/wp-json/wc/v2/products'; //woocommerce
  _urlwp = 'http://127.0.0.1/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';    //wordpress

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get(this._urlwp);
  }
  getProducts() {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("ck_9c9293adb7d3fb19f60a1dccd0cb5d4a251e9e03:cs_77a221d4655d5fb8fc2a5c85b7259c2364d59a8c"));
    headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return this.http.get(this._urlwc, { headers: headers });

  }
}
```

only Wordpress get method works fine even without authorization, but Woocommerce gives me not authorized 401 code!! [i have created consumer key and secret]

then  i tried using Postman with different authentications like

- No Auth
- Basic Auth
- OAuth 2.0

the OAuth 1.0 works fine with postman. 
How can i implement authentication angular 6 with woocommerce api?? 
or how can i user OAuth 1.0 in angular 6 like postman do??
[Postman Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45zKc.png)

Answer (score 5):

Create a service using:

```
ng g s services/woocommerce
```

This will create files `woocommerce.service.spec.ts` and `woocommerce.service.ts` under the directory `src/app/services/woocommerce`

In the `woocommerce.service.ts`, add the following code (note: you need to install crypto-js : https://github.com/brix/crypto-js):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import hmacSHA1 from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha1';
import Base64 from 'crypto-js/enc-base64';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WoocommerceService {
  nonce: string = ''
  currentTimestamp: number = 0 
  customer_key: string = 'ck_2e777dd6fdca2df7b19f26dcf58e2988c5ed1f6d'; 
  customer_secret: string = 'cs_0176cb5343903fbaebdd584c3c947ff034ecab90';  
  constructor() { }

  authenticateApi(method,url,params) {
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    this.nonce ='';
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        this.nonce += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }    
    this.currentTimestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

    let authParam:object ={
        oauth_consumer_key : this.customer_key,
        oauth_nonce : this.nonce,
        oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_timestamp : this.currentTimestamp,
        oauth_version : '1.0',
    } 
    let parameters = Object.assign({}, authParam, params);
    let signatureStr:string = '';
    Object.keys(parameters).sort().forEach(function(key) {
        if(signatureStr == '')
            signatureStr += key+'='+parameters[key];
        else
            signatureStr += '&'+key+'='+parameters[key];
    });
    let paramStr:string = '';
    Object.keys(params).sort().forEach(function(key) {

        paramStr += '&'+key+'='+parameters[key];
    });
    return url+'?oauth_consumer_key='+this.customer_key+'&oauth_nonce='+this.nonce+'&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp='+this.currentTimestamp+'&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature='+Base64.stringify(hmacSHA1(method+'&'+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&'+encodeURIComponent(signatureStr),this.customer_secret+'&'))+paramStr;

  }
}
```

The `authenticateApi` function builds and returns the url to be used for the woocommerce api call. The code is self explanatory, and I will not get into explaining it, but just in case refer to [this link](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication) on how the url is built. It's actually more about building the `auth-signature` parameter.

Here is how we will use this service in any component say for example a product component we import this service:

`import { WordpressService } from '../services/wordpress/wordpress.service';`

Also import Router and ActivatedRoute as follows:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

We want this to get the slug part of the url. To do that, pass parameters in the constructor as follows:

```
constructor(private woocommerce: WoocommerceService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.productSlug = params.slug )
  }
```

Here we are going to use the woocommerce service . We created httpclient for making http request to the woocommerce api, and activated route to get product slug. The `params.slug` refers to the variable used in angular routing routes i.e.

```
{
    path: 'product/:slug',
    component: ProductComponent
},
```

You also need to create productSlug variable in the component to hold the slug:

```
productSlug: string;
```

On ng init, call the service:

```
ngOnInit() {     
    this.params = {slug:this.productSlug}
    let producturl:string = this.woocommerce.authenticateApi('GET','http://localhost/shop/wp-json/wc/v2/products',this.params);
        this.http.get(producturl).subscribe((wc_data:any) => { 
        this.product = wc_data[0];  
        this.params = {}
        let productvariationurl:string = this.woocommerce.authenticateApi('GET','http://localhost/shop/wp-json/wc/v2/products/'+this.product.id+'/variations',this.params);
        this.http.get(productvariationurl).subscribe((wc_pv_data:any) => {
            this.productVariations = wc_pv_data;
        });
        this.params = {include:this.product.related_ids}
        let productrelatedurl:string = this.woocommerce.authenticateApi('GET','http://localhost/shop/wp-json/wc/v2/products',this.params);
        this.http.get(productrelatedurl).subscribe((wc_r_data:any) => {
            this.productRelated = wc_r_data;            
        });         
    }); 
 }
```

As you see, here I am getting all product with a particular slug. Then getting all variations of that product, and getting related products 
here is the full code of product component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { WoocommerceService } from '../services/woocommerce/woocommerce.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.scss']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  product: any;
  productVariations: any;
  selectedvariation: number;
  selectedquantity: number;
  productRelated: any;
  productSlug: number;
  variationSelected: string;
  params: object = {}
  constructor( private woocommerce: WoocommerceService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.productSlug = params.slug )
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.params = {slug:this.productSlug}
    let producturl:string = this.woocommerce.authenticateApi('GET','http://localhost/shop/wp-json/wc/v2/products',this.params);
        this.http.get(producturl).subscribe((wc_data:any) => { 
        this.product = wc_data[0];  
        this.params = {}
        let productvariationurl:string = this.woocommerce.authenticateApi('GET','http://localhost/shop/wp-json/wc/v2/products/'+this.product.id+'/variations',this.params);
        this.http.get(productvariationurl).subscribe((wc_pv_data:any) => {
            this.productVariations = wc_pv_data;
        });
        this.params = {include:this.product.related_ids}
        let productrelatedurl:string = this.woocommerce.authenticateApi('GET','http://localhost/shop/wp-json/wc/v2/products',this.params);
        this.http.get(productrelatedurl).subscribe((wc_r_data:any) => {
            this.productRelated = wc_r_data;            
        });         
    }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful.